# Powershell functions not recognized

Tags: powershell

The term 'AutomatedTest' is not recognized is a name of cmdlet......

but I don't know why.

But Powershell ISE works,

Function as below

```
if($DefaultPool.GetMachines().Name -eq $TestMachineOne)
 {
   MultiMachineTest
 }else{
   AutomatedTest
 }

function AutomatedTest()
{
   Write-host "test"
}
```

Comment: Move your function definition before your call.  It works in ISE because you've already run your script, so the functions in memory from the previous run.

Answer (score 1):

Add your function at the top of your script so that it's loaded before executing it.

```
function AutomatedTest()
{
   Write-host "test"
}

if($DefaultPool.GetMachines().Name -eq $TestMachineOne)
    {
       MultiMachineTest
    }else{
        AutomatedTest
    }
```

Comment: but I follow this , is no response, not write host test

Comment: if there is no response, it's because `$DefaultPool.GetMachines().Name` not equals `$TestMachineOne`.  Reverse your 2 functions in the condition and see what happens.